# Remove ACLs for a specific group on massive folders

Tags: function, powershell, permissions, acl

I have to remove a specific ACL entry (a group) for some massive sized folders full of files (250TB approximately). The inheritance is a mess so they have better be removed by folder (and subfolders) and item by item.

I use the NTFSSecurity module at https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity to tinker with the Acls.

I have a functional function but the problem is that it takes (measured) 16,5 Seconds per Gigabyte to remove the offending Acl. This means that it could take serveral days for all the Acls to be removed, and the folder is frequents accessed by many users and apps so the downtime is at most of 48 hours (weekend).

```
Function Remove-ACl {
  Param
  (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)][Alias("S")]$SourceFolder,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)][Alias("O")]$AclObject,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $False, Position = 2)][Alias("L")]$LogsFolder=$env:TEMP
  )

$LogDate = Get-Date -Format MMddyyyy.HHmmss
$FDListErrors = "$LogsFolder\FolderErrors.$LogDate.txt"
$FLListErrors = "$LogsFolder\FileErrors.$LogDate.txt"
$FDListOk = "$LogsFolder\FolderOk.$LogDate.txt"
$FLListOk = "$LogsFolder\FileOk.$LogDate.txt"


$Message = "Permissions for $AclObject removed on "


Try {$Folders = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories($SourceFolder, '*.*', 'AllDirectories')} catch {$_ | Out-File -FilePath $FDListErrors -Append -NoClobber}
Try {$Files = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($SourceFolder, '*.*', 'AllDirectories')} catch {$_ | Out-File -FilePath $FLListErrors -Append -NoClobber}

$SourceFolder | Get-NTFSAccess -Account $AclObject | Remove-NTFSAccess

Foreach ($Fd in $Folders)
    {
        Try {
                Get-ChildItem -Force $Fd | Get-NTFSAccess -Account $AclObject | Remove-NTFSAccess
                $Message+$Fd | Out-File -FilePath $FDListOk -Append -NoClobber

            } catch {$_ | Out-File -FilePath $FDListErrors -Append -NoClobber}
    }

Foreach ($Fl in $Files)
    {

           Try {
                Get-ChildItem -Force $Fl | Get-NTFSAccess -Account $AclObject | Remove-NTFSAccess
                $Message+$Fl | Out-File -FilePath $FLListOk -Append -NoClobber

            } catch {$_ | Out-File -FilePath $FLListOk -Append -NoClobber}     



    }

}
```

I would like to improve the speed for this function to be executed.I already list the folders and files quite fastly by invoking the [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories and [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles methods but the processing of the Acl removal itself takes ages

Comment: You could try rewriting so that it uses Start-Job to run concurrent jobs for the removal? However it'll take some careful coding and you will also run up against resource issues if there are too many files - there'll be a limit to how many jobs you can run without the machine you run the script on grinding to a halt. If you have high CPU counts in your virtual infrastructure though you could create a VM with lots of CPUs/RAM to run it on, however if this is a windows file server the best speed would be running it natively.

Comment: Crazy idea, but the PowerShell 7 Preview has a new Foreach -Parallel option that makes running parallel processes waaay easier.  I've used it for a few jobs already and it worked great.  You might need to be careful about folder levels, I am not sure what sort of contention you might run into if you try to update a folder underneath a folder you are already trying to update.

Comment: Also, since you are processing every directory recursively, you could try not to propagate the change by setting the -PropagationFlags parameter.  I would test it out in a non-production set of folders to see if it behaves the way you expect.

Comment: Hey @ScottHeath; thanks for the tip. I downloaded the PS preview 5 and after some learning (quite honestly, I had never used  Foreach-Object before) improvements have been noticed...cut the time in half by setting the Throttle limit to 20, testing it with additional threads. However, it still takes a lot... I will dig deeper into creating concurrent jobs and maybe combining it with parallel processing.